# How to add Timer and add categories to hangman

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i use the source code from microsoft of Hangman 
here is the link to the source code
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/HangMan-C-version-e0d17f1b/view/SourceCode

and i selected the c# version

Now i don't know to add the timer and some categories.

Comment: Do not link to code. Share the code part where you have problems. Otherwise nobody is willing to help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a timer to your form, in visual studio, go to the toolbox, type timer and a timer control will appear. Drag and drop this control on your form

timer1 has been added to your control, visible in the bar beneath your form

or in code :

```
public MyControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var timer = new Timer();
  timer.Name = "timer1";
  Controls.Add(timer);
}
```

to get your timer control

```
public Timer timer1
{
  get { return (Timer)Controls["timer1"]; }
}
```

if you want to create an event:

```
//beware that your control must exist!!!
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Your Code
}
```